# Generating a CSV file

Tags: excel, csv

I am having problems  converting an MSaccess table  that contains a 12 digits barcode-number field to CSV file
The barcode field is defined as text!
I tried exporting  to Excel and saving the Excel file to CSV  or exporting it to CSV But but that did not work either (even when the field is defined as text).
The problem is that some barcodes start with zero  which gets truncated  and that displays a scientific notation  instead of  displaying  the barcode string.
My Question is:  How can I generate a  CSV file that is stored as an Excel spread sheet?
any help is appreciated
Dory

Nick McDermaid  thanks for your comment. When looking in a text editor  everything  looks perfect.....You mean the people requesting it on my website are actually using it as text file and do not care about the way it looks in a spread sheet? if so then I am just chasing a wild goose!  is that what you mean?

Comment: What is the purpose of creating the CSV file? to view or to send to another system? The real test is to open the CSV file in a text editor and see what it looks like.

Comment: Do you have any response to the comment?

Comment: That's exactly right.  If you are supplying a CSV and it looks right in the text editor then you are chasing a wild goose.  It sounds like you've been testing your file by double clicking it, you may get different results by importing it through the data tab.  Excel is notorious for auto-formatting data.